# Ansible - iterate over items and execute task if value doesn't exist

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I want to iterate over items, check if fluxcd value exist in any of the items, and if fluxcd doesn't exists I want to execute task using when condition. So far I wrote this:

```
- name: Check flux status
  k8s_facts: 
    api_version: v1
    kind: Namespace
    kubeconfig: "{{ kubeconfig if kubeconfig_exists else omit }}"
  register: namespace_result
```

```
- name: Delete flux 
  k8s: 
    state: absent
    definition: "{{ lookup('template', 'flux-deletion.yaml') }}"
    kubeconfig: "{{ kubeconfig if kubeconfig_exists else omit }}"
    wait: True
  when: item.metadata.name != "fluxcd"
  with_items: "{{ namespace_result.resources }}"    
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Output (debug code provided by: Zeitounator):

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.metadata.name }} meets the condition"
  with_items: "{{ namespace_result.resources }}"
  when: item.metadata.name != "fluxcd"
```

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'metadata': {'name': 'default', 'selfLink': '/api/v1/namespaces/default', 'uid': '9cf3a983-df77-4905-8650-4bd43f1d2e8e', 'resourceVersion': '149', 'creationTimestamp': '2020-01-09T15:48:21Z'}, 'spec': {'finalizers': ['kubernetes']}, 'status': {'phase': 'Active'}, 'apiVersion': 'v1', 'kind': 'Namespace'}) => {
    "msg": "default meets the condition"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'metadata': {'name': 'fluxcd', 'selfLink': '/api/v1/namespaces/fluxcd', 'uid': '83b159be-8aeb-45ef-b5b5-5f0b6c8a098e', 'resourceVersion': '1433997', 'creationTimestamp': '2020-01-15T08:18:43Z'}, 'spec': {'finalizers': ['kubernetes']}, 'status': {'phase': 'Active'}, 'apiVersion': 'v1', 'kind': 'Namespace'}) 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'metadata': {'name': 'kube-node-lease', 'selfLink': '/api/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease', 'uid': '04199d99-5527-4455-a22f-d42abedf87eb', 'resourceVersion': '35', 'creationTimestamp': '2020-01-09T15:48:18Z'}, 'spec': {'finalizers': ['kubernetes']}, 'status': {'phase': 'Active'}, 'apiVersion': 'v1', 'kind': 'Namespace'}) => {
    "msg": "kube-node-lease meets the condition"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'metadata': {'name': 'kube-public', 'selfLink': '/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public', 'uid': 'e84d01de-d053-4c28-af8b-fd5b55de4c41', 'resourceVersion': '29', 'creationTimestamp': '2020-01-09T15:48:18Z'}, 'spec': {'finalizers': ['kubernetes']}, 'status': {'phase': 'Active'}, 'apiVersion': 'v1', 'kind': 'Namespace'}) => {
    "msg": "kube-public meets the condition"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'metadata': {'name': 'kube-system', 'selfLink': '/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system', 'uid': '6b6a50ee-a2f3-4bc7-9342-553a2acd79d2', 'resourceVersion': '16', 'creationTimestamp': '2020-01-09T15:48:18Z'}, 'spec': {'finalizers': ['kubernetes']}, 'status': {'phase': 'Active'}, 'apiVersion': 'v1', 'kind': 'Namespace'}) => {
    "msg": "kube-system meets the condition"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'metadata': {'name': 'tiller', 'selfLink': '/api/v1/namespaces/tiller', 'uid': 'eb889937-3012-41e8-86d5-f2d4679d23ac', 'resourceVersion': '1467903', 'creationTimestamp': '2020-01-15T11:17:18Z'}, 'spec': {'finalizers': ['kubernetes']}, 'status': {'phase': 'Active'}, 'apiVersion': 'v1', 'kind': 'Namespace'}) => {
    "msg": "tiller meets the condition"
}
```

But when I run this, it seems to me like it will check first field in the list where value is default and it will automatically execute task. 
I don't have experience with ansible, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your output (i.e. debug output) is not aligned with the task you give as an example (i.e. run k8s module). Can you please provide a correct [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? Thanks

Comment: I've updated post, output is only for example. My problem is with iteration, I'm not sure how can I check every value in "msg" and execute task if "fluxcd" doesn't exist. Can I join every item in one string and use regex for check? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you port your condition to the `debug` task, you will see that it is skipped when condition is not met:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.metadata.name }} meets the condition"
  with_items: "{{ namespace_result.resources }}"
  when: item.metadata.name != "fluxcd"
```

This will validate how your task loops and checks your condition. You can then replace the `debug` module with `k8s` and it will skip the exact same way.

Comment: Did you actually run the debug with the when clause to see how it works ? Loop repeats the task for every item. If the condition is not met the specific iteration will be skipped. Now if you want to totally skip all iteration in the loop if a global condition is met on your list, it's an other story. But in this case you should edit your question and add some precisions.

Comment: I accidentally deleted my comment. You are right, this works, thanks for help.